# Enum Constructor using switch (this)

Tags: java, enums

In my enum constructor, I'm trying to initialize their members. I need to use a switch statement to know which enum is currently being instantiated. However for some reason `this` seems to return `null` which makes little sense to me. Is `this` `null` until the constructor completes? If so, how can I differentiate which enum is being constructed at run time? The example below is a simplified version of my actual code to demonstrate the problem.

```
Food f = Food.APPLE;
System.out.println(f.getTastes());
```

Food Enum

```
public enum Food
{
    APPLE,
    PANCAKES,
    PASTA;

    private List<String> tastes = new ArrayList<>();

    Food()
    {
        switch(this)
        {
        case APPLE:
            tastes.add("Sour");
            tastes.add("Sweet");
            break;
        case PANCAKES:
            tastes.add("Dough-y");
            break;
        case PASTA:
            tastes.add("Creamy");
            tastes.add("Rich");
            tastes.add("Velvet");
        }
    }

    public List<String> getTastes()
    {
        return tastes;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Food.<init>(Food.java:18)
    at Food.<clinit>(Food.java:10)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Food.values(Food.java:8)
    at Food$1.<clinit>(Food.java:18)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: This is quite a roundabout way of differentiating your enum values - you should pass these in as parameters to the constructor.

Comment: The constructor has to be called to create the enum constants. So you can't expect the enum constants to work inside the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I`m not sure if this would suit you, but i belive to be the correct pattern, instead of figuring out what taste each food have in constructor, you could just declare it.

```
public enum Food
{
  APPLE("good", "sweet"),
  PANCAKES("delicious","omg"),
  PASTA("too fat", "but its gud");

  private List<String> tastes = new ArrayList<>();

      Food(String ... tastes) {
        // add to the list
     }
  }
```

Comment: If you really want to add those tastes on a different place, i would suggest making another class that builds up the food enum object for you

Comment: To do this method, I would have to somehow initialize the enum in one line. That's not always possible (unless you make silly helper functions). I feel like this does not answer my question accurately. I know of correct enum instantiation but it does not explain the null pointer exception nor how to correct it in this fashion.

Comment: @Hatefiend - Hopefully the duplicate question explains where the NPE comes from?

Comment: `tastes` should be immutable in this case. Better use `List.of()` in constructor, for example.